# Output_field exists in local version but not on website, version of python and django is the same

Tags: python, django

I have a Django website locally and as a hosted version (local version for tests and development). It uses the same version for everything (Python 3.9, Django 3.1.3). I never had any problems with features working in one of the instances and not the other. I am trying to multiply two attributes for every object and then add it together. (it calculates the total weight so: `weight*quantity+weight*quantity+...`. The problem appeared when I tried using `ExpressionWrapper`. Everything works great locally but not on hosted version. Here's the line that causes error and the error itself.

```
waga = Produkt.objects.filter(zamowienie=138).aggregate(sum=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('waga') * F('ilosc')), output_field=DecimalField()))['sum']
```

Error:

```
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Expression contains mixed types: DecimalField, IntegerField. You must set output_field.
Exception Location: /usr/home/stolarz/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py, line 303, in _resolve_output_field
```

As you can see the error states I did not use `output_field` but i clearly did. I'm a bit confused. What could possibly cause this situation?

Comment: You have to set it in ExpressionWrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper)

> ExpressionWrapper surrounds another expression and **provides access to
> properties, such as output_field**, that may not be available on other
> expressions. ExpressionWrapper **is necessary when using arithmetic on
> F() expressions with different types** as described in [Using F() with
> annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations).

So in your case

```
Sum(ExpressionWrapper(F('waga') * F('ilosc'), output_field=DecimalField())
```

As @Abdul Aziz Barkat spotted

You don't even need to use `ExpressionWrapper` as `Sum` is [Aggregate() expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#aggregate-expressions)

```
Sum(F('waga') * F('ilosc'), output_field=DecimalField())
```

Comment: As you can see I am using ExpressionWrapper -> `sum=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('waga') * F('ilosc'))`

Comment: yes and you should set  output_field inside, sorry for not being clear

Comment: You made me look at something I didn't at first. I used ExpressionWrapper on Sum(), not F(). I have no idea why it worked locally though. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I looked it at the glance and saw output_field on Sum but didn't notice that Sum is inside of ExpressionWrapper so yes it should be other way around

Comment: An aggregate function can take an `output_field` kwargs so `ExpressionWrapper` can also be replaced `Sum(F('waga') * F('ilosc'), output_field=DecimalField())`

Comment: Yes because Sum is extended Expression class through Func, so there is no need for ExpressionWrapper, it is well spotted that I should also point to this